# R - subscript out of bounds with stringer and grep in lapply function

Tags: r, lapply, stringr, subscript

My goal is to extract strings of digits with fixed length (8 digits) from multiple text files in several folders after matching a certain pattern.

I have spent the whole day in order build a lapply-function out of it, so all the files (up to 20) in the subdirectories can be processed automatically. I fail though. The code of the workflow is executable, however due to my poor knowledge of `R` limited to only one file.

In between the lines with numbers there is one string per file, each different, which I want to extract. The output of the string extraction should be stored folderwise.

The strings have the following structure: `String[one or two digits]_[eight digits]` . For example, String1_20220101 or String12_20220108. I want to extract the part after the underscore.

The text files are structured in this way with each over 10000 rows.

Example for file 1:

```
     X1  X2
1 1000 100
2 1050 100
3 1100 100
4 1150 100
5 1200 100
6 String1_20220101
7 1250 100
8 1300 100
9 1350 100
10 1400 100

x1 <- list(c(seq(1000,1400, by=50)))
[1] 1000 1050 1100 1150 1200 1250 1300 1350 1400

x2 <- list(c(rep(100, 9)))
[1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

File 2:

```
   x1     x2
1 2000  200
2 3000  200
3 4000  200
4 5000  200
5 6000  200
6 7000  200
7 String12_20220108
8 8000  200
9 9000  200
10 10000 200


x1 <- list(c(seq(1000,10000,by=1000)))
[1]  1000  2000  3000  4000  5000  6000  7000  8000  9000 10000

x2 <- list(c(rep(200, 9)))
[1] 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200
```

The files lie in numbered folders and derive their name from the folder number and belong to one observation.

My code for folder 1:

```
library(stringr)

Folderno1 <- list.files(path = "path/to/file/1/",
pattern = "*.txt",
full.names = TRUE)

FUN <- function(Folder1) {
folder_input <- readLines(Folderno1)
string <- grep("String[0-9]_", folder_input, value = TRUE)
output <- capture.output(as.numeric(str_extract_all(string, "(?<=[0-9]{1,2}_)[0-9]+")[[1]]))
write(output, file="/pathtofile/String1.tex")
}

lapply(Folderno1, FUN)

Error in str_extract_all(string, "(?<=[0-9]{1,2}_)[0-9]+")[[1]] : 
subscript out of bounds
```

The above error message appears. The file String1.tex can be overwritten despite the error message, but only with one result:

```
[1] 20220101
```

The rerun with debug shows:

```
function (x) 
.Internal(withVisible(x))
```

Could you please guide me how the workflow can be successfully changed, so every file can be processed? I can not get my head around it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the same file every time (`write(output, file="/pathtofile/String1.tex")`) in the function. Probably, you want to create a new `.tex` file for every `.txt` file.

From the error message I think there are certain files which do not have the pattern that we are looking for (`String[0-9]_`). `String[0-9]_` will not work with 2 digit numbers like `String12_20220108`. I have changed it to use `String[0-9]+_`. To be on safer side I have also added an `if` condition to check the length of output.

Try this solution -

```
Folderno1 <- list.files(path = "path/to/file/1/",
                        pattern = "*.txt",
                        full.names = TRUE)

FUN <- function(Folder1) {
  #Read the file
  folder_input <- readLines(Folder1)
  #Extract the line which has "String" in it
  string <- grep("String[0-9]+_", folder_input, value = TRUE)
  #If such line exists
  if(length(string)) {
    #Remove everything till underscore to get 8-digit number
    output <- sub('.*_', '', string)
    #Remove everything after underscore to get "String1", "String12"
    out <- sub('_.*', '', string)
    #Write the output
    write(output, file= paste0('/pathtofile/', out, '.tex'))
  }
}

lapply(Folderno1, FUN)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It would work like intended. Unfortunately, due to tiredness last night I forgot to mention that after the eight digits there is a parenthesis which is followed by characters and a digit at the end of the line. E.g. String1_20220101) Abcdefgh abcdeDIGIT Can somehting like \\\( be used? Thanks once again.

Comment: How about replacing `output` line with `output <- sub('.*_(\\d+).*', '\\1', string)` ? I tried it on `sub('.*_(\\d+).*', '\\1', 'String1_20220101) Abcdefgh abcde')` and I think it works.